# Realm data stored on UITextField are empty, print(entry) works

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, realm

I have a Realm database, in which I store my entries. Storing & querying work without any problems. I know in Swift Realm Results are lazy but I can't get why this is happening.
My code:

```
newsItems = databaseHelper.retriveAllNews()
//[...] this is on tableView method
let currentNew = newsItems[indexPath.row]
print(currentNew)
newsCell.newsTitle.text = currentNew.title
newsCell.newsText.text = currentNew.info
```

the `print(..)` statement works perfectly and I get all the info stored in the `currentNew` object, but when I set the info into the UITextField `newsCell.newsTitle` & `newsCell.newsText` them are displayed empty, as the Result have not been loaded yet. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you please share the declaration of your model class?

Comment: @bdash thanks! Haha, noticed now I did not updated them with dynamic as requested, that solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of the problem you're seeing is omitting the `dynamic` modifier from the property declarations in your model class. The `dynamic` modifier is necessary to ensure that Realm has an opportunity to intercept access to the properties, giving Realm an opportunity to read / write the data from the file on disk. Omitting these properties results in the Swift compiler accessing the instance variables directly, cutting Realm out of the loop.

Comment: Just answered my self with the same solution! Thanks by the way. But I still can't understand with the print() statement works and the assignment are not! However, you find the solution

Comment: The `print()` works because creating a string representation of the object calls an internal Realm method that iterates the object's properties from Objective-C. The `dynamic` modifier is only relevant to Swift code accessing the properties.